# Matching strings without single braces

Tags: php, regex

I am working on regular expression based validation of some user input fields. The string that needs to be validated in given below

```
{{custName}} With Account Number {{accountnumber}} Your Balance Is {{message_abc.com}}
```

and the respective regular expression to check the string is given below

```
[{{[A-Za-z,_.}} ]*
```

which works absolutely fine for the above mentioned string, but what I want is: if the string is e.g:

```
{custName} With Account Number {accountnumber} Your Balance Is {message_abc.com}
```

It would give an error.

Answer (score 1):

This matches strings that don't have any single brace:

```
^(?:(?!(?<!{){(?!{))(?!(?<!})}(?!}))[{[A-Za-z,_.} ])*$
```

- `(?!(?<!{){(?!{))` : avoid to match openning brace without another before or after
- `(?!(?<!})}(?!}))` : avoid to match closing brace without another before or after

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fYbjUv/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can match from `{{...}}` followed by the character class without the space and without the curly braces.

Then repeat that 0+ as a whole and match at least a single times the `{{...}}` part.

```
^(?:\{\{[A-Za-z,_.]*}}[A-Za-z,_. ]*)*\{\{[A-Za-z,_.]*}}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\{\{[A-Za-z,_.]*}}` Match `{{...}}}`
  - `[A-Za-z,_. ]*` Optionally repeat any of the listed chars in the character class
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times
- `\{\{[A-Za-z,_.]*}}` Match at least a single occurrence of `{{...}}}`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA1yJV/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/44rkhM)

If there can also be content before and after:

```
^[A-Za-z,_. ]*(?:\{\{[A-Za-z,_.]*}}[A-Za-z,_. ]*)+[A-Za-z,_. ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H6pu62/1)